# req.files showing undefined for body-parse

Tags: node.js

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })); 
app.use(bodyParser.json()); 

app.post('/upload', function (req, res) {
  console.log('hari :'+req.body.purpose);
  timeNow = Date.now();
  var jobID = timeNow + '_' + Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000000000000) + 1);
  var rethinkObj = config.rethinkdb;
  var data = {
    "id": jobID,
    "finished_at": timeNow,
    "last_update": timeNow,
    "log": "add job",
    "process_instructions": "",
    "start_at": timeNow,
    "status": "in-progress"
  }
  rethink.insertDataIntoTable(rethinkObj, data).then(function(insertedData){
    console.log(insertedData);
    console.log('new row inserted into RethinkDB', data.id);

    uploadFile(req, res, jobID);

  })
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should add a middleware for work with files, because bodyParser don't work with them. Quote from bodyParser's readme:

This does not handle multipart bodies, due to their complex and typically large nature. For multipart bodies, you may be interested in the following modules:

- busboy and connect-busboy
- multiparty and connect-multiparty
- formidable
- multer